# Loading php foreach values in jQuery bar chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, bar-chart

I'm working on jQuery bar chart.
Using date range to search free and occupied spaces, entry and exit out of total,
Following snapshot will give brief idea of search result;
[Search result http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/search-result.jpg](http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/search-result.jpg)

and php forearch is;

```
<?php if(count($occupied) < 1) return; foreach ($occupied as $key=>$value): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total_space; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $real_data[$key] + $dep_data[$key];?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $total_space - $real_data[$key] - $dep_data[$key]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (array_key_exists($key, $real_data))?$real_data[$key]:0;?></td>
    <td><?php echo (array_key_exists($key, $dep_data))?$dep_data[$key]:0;?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Bar Char looks like this
[Search result http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/barchart.jpg](http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/barchart.jpg)

following is the jQuery code;

```
    $(function(){
        $('#graph').graphify({
            //options: true,
            start: 'bar',
            obj: {
                id: 'ggg',
                width: '100%',
                height: 375,
                xGrid: true,
                legend: true,
                title: 'Departure vs Return',
                points: [
                    [7, 26, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33, 178, 160, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33, 178, 160, 178, 160, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33, 178, 160,450],
                    [32, 46, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52, 134, 145, 52, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52, 134, 145, 145, 52, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52, 134, 145,300]
                ],
                pointRadius: 3,
                colors: ['#428bca', '#1caf9a'],
                xDist: 40,
                dataNames: ['Departure', 'Return'],
                xName: 'Day',
                tooltipWidth: 15,
                animations: true,
                pointAnimation: true,
                averagePointRadius: 5,
                design: {
                    tooltipColor: '#fff',
                    gridColor: '#f3f1f1',
                    tooltipBoxColor: '#d9534f',
                    averageLineColor: '#d9534f',
                    pointColor: '#d9534f',
                    lineStrokeColor: 'grey',
                }
            }
        });
    });

Private.defaults = function() {
    return {
        //Days or Date Range
        x: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
        y: 20,
        attachTo: 'body'
    };
};
```

And HTML to show barchart;

```
<div id="graph"></div>
```

I need help how can i put values into arrays and load into barchart depending on date range.

<del>points: [
        [''],
        ['']
    ],

    x: ['']</del>

**Edited & Updated Question**

@Marcos Dimitrio answer pointed that I used wrong arrays as reference in question before; my appologies, following are correct depart n return arrays;

```
points: [
    ['<?php echo $real_data[$key];?>'],
    ['<?php echo $dep_data[$key]; ?>']
],

x: ['<?php echo $key; ?>']//No of Days in X-Axis If no x-axis arrays define, chart will not be loaded.
```

And After using code in answer according to your instructions, I'm getting this, I defined Days (x-axis) manually like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

[No-Bars http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/no-bars.jpg](http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/no-bars.jpg)
[No Data in Table http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/bar-chart-table.jpg](http://www.shehary.com/stackimages/bar-chart-table.jpg)

Following is rest of php code;

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);     
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);         
include_once 'parkingdetail.php'; //This file is doing all the calculation
//Add one day to today               
$real_data = array();
$total_space = 0;
$dep_data = array();
$occupied = array();
getParkData($to,$total_space,$real_data,$dep_data,$occupied,$av,$tp,$tpbooking,$from);
ksort($occupied);
//$total_space is fixed 2000
//$real_data is Depart
//$dep_data is Return
//$occupied is total sim of $real_data+$dep_data
```

[Graph Working Example](http://uriahsanders.github.io/examples/graph.html)

Regards.

Comment: Is the part `points: [ ['<?php echo ... ... ?>'] ],` inside the loop?

Comment: No, I put it in questuon just only for reference that how can i put arrays into points so values load in barchart.

Comment: I'm kinda lost after your edit. Before you had a clear question: "how can i put values into arrays and load into barchart depending on date range". Now, it's not clear to me what you need.

Comment: The need is same, if u look at last 2 snapshots, its after I integrated your solution, barchart is not loading the arrays, and the rest of the code is just for reference and the graph working example at the bottom of the question is the same graph I'm using.

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($dep_data);` after filtering it with `isWithinRange`? What do you get? In my example, I did `$points_departure[] = $real_data[$key] + $dep_data[$key];`, perhaps you needed `$points_departure[$key] = $real_data[$key] + $dep_data[$key];` (note the **$points_departure[$key]**).

Comment: On print_r($dep_data); I'm getting this Array ( [02-June-2015] => 116 [01-June-2015] => 159 [31-May-2015] => 197 [0] => 270 ), the $from and $to dates are 01 June

Comment: Check out the source code, after you access it from your browser, see if the code generated by your PHP script is in the correct format expected by the plugin. Also check if $key is the same as the keys inside your arrays, since you're getting all of those "undefined" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can filter the data into new arrays:

```
<?php
$start = "01-June-2015";
$end = "03-June-2015";

$points_departure = array();
$points_return = array();

foreach (array_keys($occupied) as $key) {
    if (isWithinRange($key, $start, $end)) {
        $points_departure[] = $real_data[$key] + $dep_data[$key];
        $points_return[] = $total_space - $real_data[$key] - $dep_data[$key];
    }
}

function isWithinRange($key, $start, $end) {
    $keyDate = DateTime::createFromFormat ("d-M-Y", $key);
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat ("d-M-Y", $start);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat ("d-M-Y", $end);

    return $keyDate >= $startDate and $keyDate <= $endDate;
}
```

After that, you need to send those to JavaScript. You can do it by AJAX, or you can use an easier approach and just put it on top of your page:

```
<script>
var points_departure = <?php echo json_encode($points_departure); ?>;
var points_return = <?php echo json_encode($points_return); ?>;
</script>
```

which will give you:

```
<script>
var points_departure = [7,26,33];
var points_return = [32, 46, 75];
</script>
```

Then simply replace the points data with the variables you created:

```
points: [
    points_departure,
    points_return
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global JavaScript variable like so:

```
<script>
var dataPoints = [ <?php echo implode(', ',$pointsArray) ?>];
</script>
```

and then reference it in the plugin like this:

```
point: dataPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you, during your `foreach` loop, create the two arrays that you're going to use?

```
$one = array();
$two = array();
foreach ($occupied as $key=>$value):
    // the rest of the stuff you do...
    $one[] = $real_data[$key] + $dep_data[$key];
    $two[] = $total_space - $real_data[$key] - $dep_data[$key];
endforeach;
```

Then, in your JavaScript where you define your graph data, `implode()` the results into a list.

```
points: [
    [<?php echo implode(", ", $one); ?>],
    [<?php echo implode(", ", $two); ?>]
],
```